# Update MenuBar text daily on OS X

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, swift

Hello I want to create app with changing MenuBar text everyday at 00:00 from some system call.
For example in menu bar will be text Today celebrating Martin ... tomorrow will be : Today celebrating Michael ...

Comment: Ask your grand-mom if she understands what you are talking about.  Draw a picture if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the NSTimer controller for making a changes on MenuBar everyday ...

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, you want something that has separate "days" at the top of your screen?

I am developing an app right now that requires something similar.

You're going to want to create a calendar day reference that uses the device's calendar and location. Once you have this, compare that reference to a set day-- say, 1-Jan-1970.

Comment: I want to create app which display for example : today is Martin birthday... next day birthday of someone else..

Comment: Oh okay. That seems simple enough. Here is the apple developer reference for an introduction to using calendars / reminders.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html